# Dynamic comparator in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate, comparator

i was wondering is there a way to build a predicate and dynamically specify what comparator to use? For example I tried this but it crashes:

```
NSPredicate *validPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K %@ %@", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(expirationDate)), isValid ? @"<" : @">",[NSDate date]];
```

but if I hardcode the comparator in the string it doesn't crash:

```
 NSPredicate *validPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K < %@", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(expirationDate)), [NSDate date]];
```

Is there an optimal way than doing this :

```
 NSPredicate * validPredicate = nil;

if (isValid) {
    validPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K > %@", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(expirationDate)), [NSDate date]];
} else {
    validPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K < %@", NSStringFromSelector(@selector(expirationDate)), [NSDate date]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why there's an error parsing your first example but how about building the format first:

```
NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%K %@ %%@", isValid ? @"<" : @">"];
NSPredicate *validPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:format, NSStringFromSelector(@selector(expirationDate)), [NSDate date]];
```

(It's less code that the `if` but I guess it depends on your definition of "optimal".)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the proper way to do this is using the initializer on `NSComparisonPredicate`. Using a dynamically generated format string may work, but it's fragile.

```
NSPredicateOperatorType comparison = isValid ? NSGreaterThanPredicateOperatorType : NSLessThanPredicateOperatorType;

NSExpression *expirationDate = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"expirationDate"];
NSExpression *date = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:[NSDate date]];
validPredicate = [[NSComparisonPredicate alloc] initWithLeftExpression:expirationDate 
                                                       rightExpression:date 
                                                              modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier 
                                                                  type:comparison 
                                                               options:0];
```